# how to sign bytes using USB token with pin code?

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I have a USB token which have a X509Certificate/XmlDigSig on it protected by a pin code. (im not exactly sure what is that)

i am currently using the vendor's Library to sign bytes but the vendor code pops up a windows dialog requesting a pin code.

i would like to avoid the pin code popup and supply the code directly as part of my c#.

```
 public byte[] GetSignedByteArr(byte[] request)
 {
        var signAndVerifyUtil = new GovIL.SignAndVerifySDK.Providers.XmlDigSig();
        var signed = signAndVerifyUtil.Sign(request, GetSignParameters());
        return signed.ContentInfo.signedContent;
 }

 public SignParameters GetSignParameters()
 {
        return new SignParameters(new CryptoSignatureInfo(Certificate.GetSignCertificateBySerialNumber("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", true)));
 }
```

thanks to all!

Comment: Did you read the vendors documentation?  Usually the vendor will use a certificate and all the api is doing doing the signing.  But the vendor will have instructions on doing the certification without the api.

Comment: Windows CNG (RSACng/ECDsaCng/DSACng) and Windows CAPI (RSACryptoServiceProvider/DSACryptoServiceProvider) both support software-supplied PIN values, but unless the GovIL layer supports you passing it through that doesn't do you any good.  Your question is really specific to that layer.

Answer (score 0):

X509Certificate is public certificate which used by SSL/TLS. it's based on public key & private key. every one can encrypt the content using the public key but only people who own the private key can decrypt and verify the content.

So we don't know any information about your hardware key and it's SDK. 
If you use it to sign something like Cert Authorities the requested pin is private key and by the best practice you really avoid to hardcode it in your code or database, it's very risky. In this scenario maybe SDK developers forcing users to don't store the private key by exposing API which show dialog to user and don't let the developer to load key from memory or file.
You can do the pin input by simulation trick but again it's so forget it ;)

If you use the SDK for encrypting or signing something that verify somewhere else you use public key and it's wise that SDK developers let you to it by API calls, but we don't know anything about your library, so contact the SDK vendor.